# Inspect array after adding object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, nsmutablearray

The compiler doesn't give me any error and the code runs. Just curious how can I check the contents of my array after adding a new element.

In my .h file

```
@interface AddCardViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *cardNameTextField;

@end
```

In my .m file

```
@interface AddCardViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray *nameOfCards;

@end

@implementation AddCardViewController 

@synthesize cardNameTextField = _cardNameTextField;

@synthesize nameOfCards = _nameOfCards;

- (NSMutableArray *)nameOfCards 
{
    if (!_nameOfCards)
           _nameOfCards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    return _nameOfCards;
}

- (IBAction)addNewCard:(id)sender {
    [_nameOfCards addObject:self.cardNameTextField.text];
}

@end
```

Comment: You have mentioned in your question about "how to add text in array" but in last you said all works fine and you want to check something.....what exactly you want to do??

Comment: @Goti I want to check the contents of my array after clicking my UIButton.

Comment: @elppa thanks for editing the layout. How did you do it look much better? :)

Comment: Select your code and click on code sample button like {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use lazy loading (i.e. you create the object in its getter method) you have to use the getter to access the object. Do not access the object through its instance variable!

```
- (IBAction)addNewCard:(id)sender {
    [self.nameOfCards addObject:self.cardNameTextField.text];
    NSLog(@"my array content: %@", self.nameOfCards);
}
```

that's why you prefix instance variables with an underscore. It tells you to not use the instance variable directly except when it's absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)addNewCard
{
    [your_Array addObject:self.Your_textfeild.text];
}
```

Array should be NSmutable Array.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
   - (IBAction)addNewCard:(id)sender {
       [_nameOfCards addObject:self.cardNameTextField.text];
   }
```

to

```
   - (IBAction)addNewCard:(id)sender {
       [self.nameOfCards addObject:self.cardNameTextField.text];
   }
```

after that, you can see your array in NSLog like;

```
   NSLog(@"%@", self.nameOfCards);
```

Answer (score 0):

use **NSLog** to see the contents of the array i.e. `NSLog(@"%@",_nameOfCards);`

Comment: I've placed this code inside my IBAction: 
NSLog(@"contents of my array %@", _nameOfCards);

yet the console says,
contents of my array = (null)

Comment: did you alloc and intialize the array in the viewDidLoad?

Comment: you know of any reason why it gives me a null value?

Comment: ohh, ahm I forgot to include this in my post. This one is included in my .m file

- (NSMutableArray *)nameOfCards 

{

    if (!_nameOfCards) _nameOfCards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    return _nameOfCards;

}

Comment: @Hans where are you calling `nameOfCards` from?

Comment: Do you have a `viewDidLoad` or `loadView` from which you will call the `nameOfCards` method from? Otherwise, in your button action method, you are trying to access the array which hasn't been initialized

Comment: @Invincible No I do not have any. But in the code above, I already initialized my array. Everything's okay now. Thanks!